# How to compare one column against to 2 other columns in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So this is the problem Im trying to solve. The Spreadsheet has non-nummerical values in column B2, E2 and H2 and onward.

Using conditional formatting the values in column B need to be colored using these conditions:

```
Condition 1: If a value in column B is equal to any value in column E it should color the cell of the value in column B green
```

```
Condition 2: If a value in column B is NOT equal to any value in column E it should color the cell of the value in yellow
```

```
Condition 3: If a value in column B is equal to any value in column H it should color the cell of the value in column B red.
```

```
Condition 4: If a value in column B fulfills condition 2 AND 3 it should color the cell of the value purple
```

I managed to get condition 1 to 3 working using XMATCH and ISERROR.

I used these functions for 1 to 3:

```
C1: =XMATCH($B2;$E:$E)<>B2
```

```
C2: =ISERROR(XMATCH($B2;$E:$E))
```

```
C3: =XMATCH($B2;$H:$H)<>B2
```

I cant get Condition 4 working. I tried using this function:

```
=AND(MATCH($B2;$H:$H;0); ISERROR(XMATCH($B2;$E:$E)))
```

But that doesnt work because it supersceeds the functions of C2 or C3 depending on the prioritisation which isnt what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formatting rule on `B1:B3`:

```
=(COUNTIF(E:E,$B1)=0)*COUNTIF(H:H,$B1)
```

You can see that due to prioritization the cell colors purple instead of red.